# React Navigation -- Using two navigators on a single screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to create a screen that has two navigators in it where screen is a stack navigator, and on the same screen is a tab navigator nested in it whose contents are visible on 3/5 of the screen. This is my current configuration

```
const HomeStack = () => {
 return (
     <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" headerMode="none">
         <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
         <Stack.Screen name="ServiceConfig" component={ServiceConfig}/>
     </Stack.Navigator>
 );
}
```

App.js

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <HomeTabView />
</View>
```

HomeScreen.js

```
export default function HomeTabView() {
return (
    <TopTab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Recommended"
        initialLayout={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}>
        <TopTab.Screen name="Recommended" component={ListServices} />
        <TopTab.Screen name="Recent" component={ListServices} />
    </TopTab.Navigator>
);
}
```

HomeTabView.js

[This is the desired appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxm8j.png)

Comment: Share your code!

Comment: @OliverD I've shared it

Comment: Can you explain what do you need more I'm trying to understand ur point but I couldn't:/

Comment: @OliverD, I've edited and added an image that shows the desired appearance

Answer (score 0):

It should be work in following way

```
const HomeStack = () => {
 return (
     <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" headerMode="none">
         <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabView} />
         <Stack.Screen name="ServiceConfig" component={ServiceConfig}/>
     </Stack.Navigator>
 );
}
```

And your tab view should be like:

```
export default function HomeTabView() {
return (
    <TopTab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Recommended"
        initialLayout={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}>
        <TopTab.Screen name="Recommended" component={HomeScreen} />
        <TopTab.Screen name="Recent" component={ListServices} />
    </TopTab.Navigator>
);
}
```

And `ListServices` can be the part of `HomeScreen`

And your app code should be like :

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <HomeStack/>
</View>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add some context the homescreen still contains other components, please take a look at the edited question with an image of the desired appearance.

Comment: @Daniel in your case I would suggest to create the custom header and should have to use external tab components like 
https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view

Comment: Let me give it shot then

Answer (score 0):

in the home stack you render the normal Home screen, In the home screen, you added what's u want, then for the Top Tab you should implement a top tap navigation
then import it in the home screen like a component

Like this

```
const HomeStack = () => {
 return (
     <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" headerMode="none">
         ....
         <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
         ....
     </Stack.Navigator>
 );
}
```

TopTab.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';


const TopTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export const MyTopTabs = () => {
  return (
    <TopTabs.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        style: {
          marginVertical: 10,
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          borderRadius: 20,
          elevation: 0,
          marginHorizontal: 20,
        },
        tabStyle: {
          borderRadius: 20,
          height: 60,
        },
        labelStyle: {
          fontSize: 18,
        },
        activeTintColor: '#fff',
        inactiveTintColor: '#000',
        indicatorStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#000',
          height: '100%',
          borderRadius: 20,
        },
      }}
      lazy={true}>
      <TopTabs.Screen
        name=" prescription"
        options={{
          title: 'titlee..',
        }}
        component={OpenedAppointments}
      />
      <TopTabs.Screen
        name="nonPresicrpstion"
        options={{
          title: 'title here',
        }}
        component={CompletedAppointments}
      />
    </TopTabs.Navigator>
  );
};


In home screen

<View style={{flex: 1}}>
         ..... Your stuff
        <TopTab />
</View>
```